# Combine controller and action parameter for ActionLink / RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My application has a view that is linked from various different other views located in different controllers. I would like to have a 'Back' button in this view that will send the user back to the previous view, which ever that may be.

To this end I have added a string attribute to the viewmodel which I would like to use to reference the originating view `/MyController/MyAction` in the `@Html.ActionLink` parameters.

Some of the views linking to this view belongs to current controller, some belong to other controllers. This means I have to pass the controller as well as the action to the ActionLink.

As it stands, my code looks something like this:

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int MyData { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back", Model.ReturnUrl)
```

This produces the undesirable result of `localhost:####/CurrentController/MyController/MyAction`

Of course I could always save two strings on the ViewModel (one for the controller and one for the action) and pass them to the ActionLink seperately, but if possible I would like to avoid that. Is there an overload of ActionLink that allows me to use a single return url string, without making implications about the controller?

Also, is it possible to achieve the same thing on the controller side, f.ex. like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoStuff(MyViewModel model)
{
    // do stuff

    return RedirectToAction(model.ReturnUrl);
}
```

Comment: Maybe adding a property  with JsonResult value (e.g: LastCallerOfFooView) in the Controller that owns Foo view so to have a centralized point of state representing the last resource that called that view.

Comment: I wouldn't overthink this. `ActionLink` is a shortcut to writing the HTML for the hyperlink without hard-coding the controller & action. But since you already know the entire Url, you can simply use a plain anchor tag. The only time it might fail is if you deployed a new web site with a different routing scheme while a user left their browser open with the outdated link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `ActionLink`. Just use an anchor tag, like this:

```
<a href='@Url.Content(Model.ReturnUrl)'>Back</a>
```

And, in your Action, you can do it like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoStuff(MyViewModel model)
{
    // do stuff

    return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
}
```

Also, another solution would be to have two properties (`ReturnController` and `ReturnAction`) in your model.